Selecting next badge doesn't work on "Track the next one" dialog on "Congratulations" notice in profile
Selecting next badge doesn't work. Example:

Steps to reproduce:

Go to a site where you haven't earned a given trackable badge and select  it as your next badge. For easy testing, use a bronze badge that can be earned in one action (e.g., Autobiographer, Disciplined, Peer Pressure, etc.).
Perform the action(s) to earn the badge. If necessary, wait for the system to award the badge (note that for the aforementioned "easy" bronze badges, the system may not notify you of having earned the badge).
Refresh your profile page and see the "Congratulations! You've earned [badge name]" screen.
Click "Track the next one" to open the badge selection dialog.
Attempt to click on any badge. Nothing happens when clicking on them.

This cannot be reproduced by clicking on the gear icon when the "Congratulations" screen hasn't come up; it can only be reproduced on the dialog produced by clicking "Track the next one" on said screen.
Tested on Chrome with Android.

Able to reproduce. Editing in steps to reproduce now.

As a workaround, one can click "Let us pick" then click the gear icon to change it to a different badge.

By the way, if I may request, please do make sure that your bug reports are clear and actionable when you initially post them. See the first paragraph of the [bug] tag's extended wiki for what bug reports should contain. Not adding that information and instead putting the onus on users to understand what you're talking about can result in otherwise perfectly legitimate reports getting downvoted and eventually automatically deleted and never seen. I'm glad I was able to salvage this and your older bug reports in time before they could be significantly downvoted, but...

...I can't keep doing so, especially if you post during a time when I'm not active on the site or if I can't understand your report despite my best effort. Please be sure to read the full guidelines for filing bug reports I linked before as well as read other bug reports users have filed and those of yours which I or others have salvaged before you file another bug report.

(To be clear, in no way am I criticizing that you're filing bugs - you're awesome at finding them and it's great that you're filing them - I'm just giving you advice as to how you can make it less likely that they'll be downvoted or ignored, which is what we all want.)

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thanks for the edit and the feedback. I thought the video would be enough for someone familiar with SE to understand the issue, but the text you added is a great complement.
